# Kafka Producer not able to send messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I am very new to Kafka.

Using Kafka 0.11

> Number of alive brokers '1' does not meet the required replication factor '3' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor')

I get the above error on sending a message for a topic

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --describe
Topic:test1 PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: test1    Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

Comment: So what is your question? The error message is quite clear to me.

Answer (score 22):

How are you starting the broker ? What is the server.properties file. The one provided with the downloaded package should have the following line :

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
```

Just to be clear the error you see is not related to the topic you are trying to publish. Today, Kafka doesn't save topic offsets for consumers in Zookeeper anymore but in "internal topics" with name __consumer_offsets. Of course, if you have 1 broker you can't have a replication factor of 3. So I'd like to take a look at your server.properties. **If the above property is missing, the default is 3.**

Comment: "If the above property is missing, the default is 3."    Seems like an important detail, otherwise you would wind up looking for a value that isn't there.  :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my error is also similar.

`ERROR [KafkaApi-2] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)`

---

Cluster : `2 Brokers (ID=1,ID=2)` with `hostname-1` and `hostname-2`
Kafka version : `1.0.1`

`listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9090,SSL://:9091,PLAINTEXT_EXT://:9092,SSL_EXT://:9093,SASL_SSL://:9094,SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9095`

and both broker `server.properties`  is set to `offsets.topic.replication.factor=1`

but I configured my advertised hostname as `hostname-1` in both broker over protocols which is being used for inter-broker communication ( and thus broker with `ID=2` keep on giving above error.

`advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://hostname-2:9090,SSL://hostname-2:9091,PLAINTEXT_EXT://<EXTERNAL_IP>:9092,SSL_EXT://<EXTERNAL_IP>:9093,SASL_SSL://hostname-1:9094,SASL_PLAINTEXT://hostname-1:9095`

correction on `SASL_SSL` and `SASL_PLAINTEXT` fixed this error.

PS : `SASL_PLAINTEXT` is `security.inter.broker.protocol` in this cluster. This error seems to be related with port availability as well.

Answer (score 1):

This means your cluster have default replication factor setting to some numbers to override this you need to edit server.properties and add replication factor parameter with your choice value

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
```

In my case i wanted to run single node kafka with single node zookeeper for that case you need to create topic with replication factor 1 otherwise you will gent an error

```
mansoor@c2dkb05-usea1d:~$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zookeeper-svc:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic mqttDeviceEvents

Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 1.
[2020-06-18 14:39:46,533] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 1.
```

the correct way to create topic is when you have single node kafka

```
mansoor@c2dkb05-usea1d:$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zookeeper-svc:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic mqttDeviceEvents
Created topic mqttDeviceEvents.
```